# How to set a labels for all instances in a GCP project that contain specific label key

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am pretty new to python and looking for a python code that will be called from AWS Lambda to update labels for all instances in gcp project that contain a specific label key/value pair.

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from typing import Dict, Iterable
from google.cloud import compute_v1
from googleapiclient import discovery
import json
import os
config = Config()


os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="creds.json"

def updateComputeLabels(data, account):
    log.info("-----")
    log.info("updating Compute Engine labels")
    RC_PlatformCode = data['NewImage']['PlatformCode']['S']
    platformcode_gcp = 'rc_platformcode'
    tagKey = data['NewImage']['Key']['S']
    tagValue = data['NewImage']['Value']['S']
    log.info("tagkey = " + tagKey)
    labelKeyLower = tagKey.lower()
    labelValueLower = tagValue.lower()
    labelKey = labelKeyLower.replace("@", "_at_")
    labelValue = labelValueLower.replace("@", "_at_")
    instance_client = compute_v1.InstancesClient.from_service_account_json('creds.json')
    service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
    request = compute_v1.AggregatedListInstancesRequest()
    project = account
    request.project = project
    request.max_results = 50

    agg_list = instance_client.aggregated_list(request=request)
    

    all_instances = {}
    print("Instances found:")
    # Despite using the `max_results` parameter, you don't need to handle the pagination
    # yourself. The returned `AggregatedListPager` object handles pagination
    # automatically, returning separated pages as you iterate over the results.
    for zone, response in agg_list:
        if response.instances:
            all_instances[zone] = response.instances
            print(f" {zone}:")
            for instance in response.instances:
                log.info("instance name -> " + instance.name)
                update_tag = False
                try:
                    labels = instance.labels
                    labelfingerprint = instance.label_fingerprint
                    log.info("tags -> " + str(labels))
                    log.info("fingerprint -> " + str(labelfingerprint))
                except ClientError:
                    continue
                for label in labels:
                    if labels["rc_platformcode"] == RC_PlatformCode:
                        log.info(
                            f"RC_PlatformCode [{RC_PlatformCode}] present for instance [{instance.name}]")
                        update_tag = True
                        break
                if update_tag:
                    create_tag = True
                    log.info("processing instance -> " + instance.name)
                    log.info("setting tag Key -> " + tagKey.lower())
                    log.info("setting tag Value -> " + tagValue.replace("@", "_at_"))
                    for label in labels:
                        log.info("checking tag -> " + label)
                        labels[tagKey.lower()] = tagValue.replace("@", "_at_")
                        instance_labels = labels
                        instances_set_labels_request_body = {
                            'labels': instance_labels,
                            'labelFingerprint': labelfingerprint
                        }
                        zone_clean = zone.replace("zones/","")
                        request = service.instances().setLabels(project=project, zone=zone_clean, instance=instance.name, body=instances_set_labels_request_body)
                        response = request.execute()
                        break
    return all_instances
```

The code I currently have is the following way but it lacks quality and I am facing error when trying to call setLabels with the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Object of type MessageMapContainer is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 60, in handler\n    updateComputeLabels(data, account)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/cloudCompute.py\", line 78, in updateComputeLabels\n    request = service.instances().setLabels(project=project, zone=zone_clean, instance=instance.name, body=instances_set_labels_request_body)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/googleapiclient/discovery.py\", line 1101, in method\n    headers, actual_path_params, actual_query_params, body_value\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/googleapiclient/model.py\", line 160, in request\n    body_value = self.serialize(body_value)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/googleapiclient/model.py\", line 273, in serialize\n    return json.dumps(body_value)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py\", line 231, in dumps\n    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py\", line 199, in encode\n    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py\", line 257, in iterencode\n    return _iterencode(o, 0)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py\", line 179, in default\n    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '\n"
  ]
}
```

Contents of instances_set_labels_request_body

```
{'labels': {'rc_platformcode': 'tst', 'rc_costcenter': '7777'}, 'labelFingerprint': '3E6RKl7bF_4='}
```

Can anyone help me or am I doing it all wrong? Thanks!

Comment: There is something wrong with the data structure **labels**. Use debug code, print the contents, and then compare with the API documentation.

Comment: the output of labels looks the following way and I am unsure what is wrong:
{'labels': {'rc_platformcode': 'tst', 'rc_costcenter': '7777'}, 'labelFingerprint': 'test123'}

Comment: Put those details in your question. Then reference the API and look up what it expects. However, what you put in your comment does not match the error message. Post the content of **instances_set_labels_request_body**. labelFingerprint will not be **test123**. Please put real data in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley this is the content of instances_set_labels_request_body:
{'labels': {'rc_platformcode': 'tst', 'rc_costcenter': '7777'}, 'labelFingerprint': '3E6RKl7bF_4='}

Comment: A quick review of your code suggests that you're using Google Cloud Client Library for Compute Engine to get the list of instances (`compute_v1.InstancesClient`) and then the API Client Library for Compute Engine to update the labels. I assume that's at least part of your problem. It **is** confusing that Google has 2 set of libraries for its services (see: [Client Libraries Explained](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained). Stick to one (probably the Cloud Client Library).

Comment: By way of simplication, all of Google's Client Libraries (Cloud and API) support a mechanism called Application Default Credentials. Using this you export the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable with a value pointing to a Service Account key and authenticating is essentially automated. In your case you then need just `compute_v1.InstancesClient()` to instantiate an authenticated client. This will simplify your code too. See [Finding Credentials Automatically](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python)

Comment: Otherwise, your approach of getting the instance(s), mutating the labels and then setting the labels (with the previous fingerprint) is correct.